# How can I select the next element using Nokogiri without calling "next_element" method?

Tags: html, css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

When I run my code on a different machine I get the following error:
**ruby: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so: undefined symbol: xmlNextElementSibling**

When the process start I get the following warning:
*WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.7.8, but has dynamically loaded 2.6.30* 
I cannot update nokogiri at the moment so I tried to dig into the source code and the problem seems to be related to the next_element method called by Nokogiri which works on my machine but explodes on the other.
Thus my question: how can I easily select the next HTML element (in particular, the next "tr" in a table)?

This is the code I am using

```
def get_weight(spot)

      frame = spot.at_css("table[id='1']").css("tr")[1]
      starter = frame.at('tr:contains("D7r5")') 
      return nil if starter == nil
      starter = starter.next_element
      peso = []
      until starter.css("td")[1].nil?          
        data = starter.css("td")[1].inner_html.gsub(/\t{0..100}/, "").strip
        ndecimal = data.scan(/[0-9]{1,4},?.?[0-9]{0,3}/).last.gsub(",", ".")
        nmeasure = data.scan(/[kK][Gg]|\s[g]\s|[g]/).last
        case nmeasure
        when (/[kK][Gg]/)
          peso << ndecimal.to_f
        when (/g|\s[g]\s|[g]/)
          peso << ndecimal.to_f / 1000
        end 
        starter.next_element.nil? ? break : starter = starter.next_element
        end 
        return peso.max == 0 ? nil : peso.max
  end
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Not sure if this will work in your case, but XPath equivalent for `next_element` is `following-sibling::*[1]`

Comment: @har07 Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for!
Please post it as an answer and I'll take it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath equivalent for `next_element` is **`following-sibling::*[1]`**. Or just **`following-sibling::*`**, if the XPath will be executed using somethng like as `at_xpath()`, which return only the first matched node by default.